# Line-height & input button height

Tags: html, css

I am creating button styles at the moment.

At the moment, they look like this:

```css
html {
    color: #555;
    background: #fefefe;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="btn">Test</a>
<input type="button" value="Test" class="btn">
<input type="submit" value="Test" class="btn">
<input type="reset" value="Test" class="btn">
<button type="button" class="btn">Test</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Test</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn">Test</button>
```

As you can see, the three buttons created using `input` look different than the rest.

After some debugging I found that it's the `line-height` declaration on the `html` element that is responsible for that.

How can I have my buttons look the same while having a `line-height` set?

Note that I am already using normalize.css.

Comment: Use `<input type="button">` insted of `<button></button>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as others have pointed out, you should set a `line-height` for your `.btn` class, however, I believe you actually want `line-height: inherit;` specifically so you actually *inherit* the line-height.

Comment: Thank you, using `inherit` actually seems a tad nicer that `normal` – let's see which answer I'll accept ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Set the same `line-height` property to elements you need

```
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution if you don't need IE support - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-appearance)

Comment: You can simplify this by just putting the line-height on the .btn class. Then you also don't run into the IE support issue mentioned by Vucko

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `line-height` to `normal`, or to any other value, for the class of elements you wish to have look the same:

```
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    line-height: normal; /* set a line-height for your elements */
}
```

```css
html {
    color: #555;
    background: #fefefe;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    line-height: normal; /* set a line-height for your elements */
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="btn">Test</a>
<input type="button" value="Test" class="btn">
<input type="submit" value="Test" class="btn">
<input type="reset" value="Test" class="btn">
<button type="button" class="btn">Test</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn">Test</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn">Test</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. But why do I need to set it inside my class? Inside normalize.css you'll find `input { line-height: normal; }`, so it should already be there.

Comment: Had you included normalize.css, I might be able to offer some advice; but I'm not sure: is the same included for the `<button>` elements?

Comment: No, it's only there for `input`. So you think the problem actually was that the `line-height` of `a` & `button` was different?

Comment: There were differences between the elements, and different css; so yeah, probably.